# How to do a right outer join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, right-join

```
'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.wid = t2.wid
          WHERE t2.wid IS NULL)
          LIMIT ' . $number;
```

This SQL lines do not give not one row back and I do not know the reason. The t1 is full of rows while the t2 is an empty table.

Comment: Because you are doing `Right outer join` with no data in that table. If you want to get the all the rows from table1 then do the `Left outer Join`.

Comment: I must do left? With left it also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to retrieve the rows in `t1` 
You will also need to avoid duplicate column names in the inner result before you make the outer select, eg `SELECT t1.*` 
Also you may need to give an alias to the derived table in the inner select eg `t3` ...

```
SELECT t3.* FROM (
    SELECT t1.* FROM t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.wid = t2.wid
    WHERE t2.wid IS NULL)
AS t3;
```

Comment: t3 is an arbitrary table alias given to the results of the inner select, it is then used to reference the intermediate results by the outer select.